# SQL command to put datetime entries into buckets

Tags: sql, rank

I have a table structure as follows:

```
timestamp
2020-03-10 04:05:44.000000
2020-03-10 04:05:44.000000
2020-03-10 04:05:44.000000
2020-03-10 04:05:44.000000
2020-03-10 07:07:44.000000
2020-03-10 07:07:44.000000
2020-03-10 13:17:44.000000
2020-03-10 13:17:44.000000
2020-03-10 13:17:44.000000
2020-03-10 13:17:44.000000
2020-03-10 13:17:44.000000
2020-03-10 13:17:44.000000
2020-03-10 13:17:44.000000
```

Every day, there are only three timestamps (time can differ, but it's always three). What I want is another column that tells me which timestamp was the first, the second, and the third, i.e. produce an output as follows:

```
timestamp                   timestamp_order
2020-03-10 04:05:44.000000  1
2020-03-10 04:05:44.000000  1
2020-03-10 04:05:44.000000  1
2020-03-10 04:05:44.000000  1
2020-03-10 07:07:44.000000  2
2020-03-10 07:07:44.000000  2
2020-03-10 13:17:44.000000  3
2020-03-10 13:17:44.000000  3
2020-03-10 13:17:44.000000  3
2020-03-10 13:17:44.000000  3
2020-03-10 13:17:44.000000  3
2020-03-10 13:17:44.000000  3
2020-03-10 13:17:44.000000  3
```

The amount of entries can differ between the three buckets. I already tried a few RANK() or NTILE() functions but couldn't get the right output, because it either gives me too high numbers (rank gives me 1,1,1,1,5,5,...) or assumes equally sized buckets.

Thanks!

Comment: Try dense_rank it should give you the required output

Comment: .....Tag the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `DENSE_RANK` with partition:

```sql
SELECT timestamp
     , DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(timestamp AS DATE) ORDER BY timestamp) AS timestamp_order
FROM t
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it works for all dbms (works at least in Postgres), but you can try:

```
SELECT 
    timestamp, 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PATITION BY date_trunc('day', timestamp) 
                       ORDER BY timestamp) as timestamp_order
FROM table
```

[`date_trunc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) extracts the day from your timestamp and rank gives you the

Answer (score 0):

Simply use DENSE RANK Function which gives you the ranking within your ordered partition.

```
SELECT timestamp, 
       DENSE_RANK( ) OVER( ORDER BY timestamp ASC ) timestamp_order
FROM #TABLE_Name;
```